# Alternative Form of Bernoulli’s Inequality

Tags: inequality

Why is the following Bernoulli inequality true (I found it here: http://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf):

> $(1+x)^r \leq  1 + (2^r-1)x$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $r \in \mathbb{R} - (0,1)$

Comment: If $n \geq 2$ is an integer then it can be easily proved by induction on n.

Comment: What is $n$?  The exponent of interest, $r$, is a real number not contained on the open interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: I was talking of the special case when $r$ is an integer. Your proof works for any r, it's better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be defined as

$$f(x)=(1+x)^r-1-(2^r-1)x \tag 1$$

From $(1)$, clearly $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=f(1)=0$.  Furthermore, $f(x)$ is twice differentiable on $[0,1]$ with

$$f'(x)=r(1+x)^{r-1}-(2^r-1) \tag 2$$

and

$$f''(x)=r(r-1)(1+x)^{r-2} \tag 3$$

Now, Rolle's Theorem guarantees there exists a point $\xi \in (0,1)$ with $f'(\xi)=0$.

---

> **ASIDE:**
>
> Setting $f'(\xi)=0$ in $(2)$ reveals that
>
> $$f'(\xi)=0 \implies \xi =\left(\frac{2^r-1}{r}\right)^{1/(r-1)}-1$$

---

Note that $f(\xi)$ is a local minimum since from $(3)$ we see that $f''(x)>0$ for $r\in \mathbb{R} - (0,1)$ and $x \in [0,1]$.

Therefore, $f(x)$ attains its maximum value at one (or both in this case) of the end points of the interval $[0,1]$.  We conclude that the maximum value of $f(x)$ is $0$ and therefore

$$(1+x)^r\le 1+(2^r-1)x$$

as was to be shown!